# bevel modifier doesn't work

Tags: modeling, bevel

The bevel modifier doesn't work on this object. Anyone an idea why?

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vLiPxpbWc8VLj8fsf5LWdlOIvS3hzUF9/view?usp=sharing

Thx!

Comment: If you disable "Clamp Overlap" you can see it works, but since some of the parts (edges) are too small to be beveled without overlapping (with current bevel setup)  ... this clamp feature prevent such deformation on entire mesh to let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you've enabled the *Clamp Overlap* option, which prevents any bevel to happen if the faces overlap. If you disable this option, some overlap will happen. If you disable *Loop Side* you'll have a better result though. Whether you plan to apply the modifier or not, you'll need to correct your topology.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem!